# The span of $n$ vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is the smallest vector space containing them

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand a proof that given a vector space $V$ over the field $F$ and $n$ vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$, $\mathrm{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is the smallest subspace containing them.

I'm fine with most of the proof, including how it is proved in Axler, but the lecture notes I'm working through include a comment I don't fully understand.

I'm ok with showing that $\mathrm{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is a subspace, that it contains $v_1, \ldots, v_n$, and that if $S$ is some other subspace of $V$ containing $v_1, \ldots, v_n$, then $\mathrm{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n) \subset S$.

The comment made in the lecture notes is: how do we know that this smallest subspace containing $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ actually exists? Axler does not provide a proof of this fact, suggesting that it isn't necessary because by definition, "smallest" means that any other subspace containing those vectors contains their span as a subset.

Is this something I need to show for a complete proof? If so, I cannot figure out how exactly I should go about proving this. The idea, I think, is taking the intersection of all subspaces containing $v_1, \ldots, v_n$, and I know that the arbitrary intersection of subspaces is a subspace, but is it necessary to show this?

Comment: Take the intersection of all subspaces containing $v_1,v_2,..,,v_n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This makes sense to me intuitively, but how would I prove that this intersection is the smallest subspace? Also, do I need to prove that this smallest subspace exists to complete the statement of this proof? I'm a bit confused, as Axler does not prove this.

Answer (score 1):

Here, $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ are $n$ vectors.

Let us fix some notation first.

We define $T = \mbox{span}\left\{ v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n \right\}$.

It is easy to verify that $T$ is a subspace of $V$.

The question is this: How to show that $T$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing the $n$ vectors $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ ?

Indeed, let us take any subspace $S$ of $V$ that contains the $n$ vectors $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$.

Since $S$ is a subspace of $V$ and $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n \in S$, $S$ must contain all the linear combinations of the $n$ vectors  $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$.

In other words, for any set of $n$ scalars $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots,
\alpha_n$,

$$
v = \alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \cdots + \alpha_n v_n \in S.
$$

This essentially means that $T \subset S$, since $v$ is a general element in the subspace $T$.

Since we have shown that $T$ is a subset of any subspace $S$ of $V$
containing the vectors $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$, we have established that $T = \mbox{span}\{ v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n \}$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing the vectors $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$. $ \ \ \ \ \ $$\blacksquare$

Comment: This proof makes sense to me, but am I correct that we don't need to prove that a "smallest subspace" exists? Or do we prove that just by establishing the property that $T \subset S$ for any such subspace $S$?

Comment: In my view, we need to prove it even though it may be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion you are having is that you are checking the equivalence of one definition with itself.

If you define $span\{v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n}\}$ as the smallest subspace containing $v_{1},...v_{n}$ then by definition it is the intersection of all subspaces containing $v_{1},...v_{n}$. You already say that you can prove that arbitrary intersection of subspaces is a subspace and hence it follows by definition that any subspace containing $v_{i}$ is the intersection. Hence $\displaystyle\text{span}\{v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n}\}=\bigcap\{\text{S is a subsapce of V containing}\,v_{1},...v_{n}\}$.

Now if you define the span as the set of all linear combination of $\{v_{i}\}$ then you can show that this set is actually the smallest subspace containing $\{v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n}\}$ and hence equals the intersection.

That is you need to check the equivalence of two definitions :-

1. $\displaystyle\text{span}\{v_{1},..,v_{n}\}=\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}v_{i}\,\,,c_{i}\in\mathbb{F}\}$

2.$span\{v_{1},...v_{n}\}$ is the is the smallest subspace containing $v_{1},...v_{n}$.

Infact you can define this for arbitrary collection of vectors $\{v_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ where $I$ is some arbirary indexing set.

Then you can again check the equivalence of two definitions:-

1. $\displaystyle\text{span}\{v_{i}\}_{i\in I}=\{\sum_{i\in I}c_{i}v_{i}\,\,,c_{i}\in\mathbb{F},c_{i}=0\,\text{for all but finitely many}\,i\in I\}=\{\sum_{\text{finite}}c_{i}v_{i}\,\,,c_{i}\in\mathbb{F}\}$.
2. $span\{v_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ is the smallest subspace of containing $\{v_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ which is equal to $\displaystyle\bigcap\{\text{S is a subsapce of V containing}\,\{v_{i}\}_{i\in I}\}$

So you see that if you prove $1\implies 2$ then it solves your "existence" crisis. And if you prove $2\implies 1$ then it means that if such a space exists then it is unique and is given by $1$.

Comment: It makes sense to me that these two definitions are equivalent, and I think I can prove that (1) implies (2), since (1) is my definition of span. But can I assert that there "exists" a smallest subspace containing $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ as in Axler's way, without referencing the intersection of subspaces containing the $v_i$?

Comment: That's what I said in the last line. Definition (1) gives you a possible candidate for such a smallest subspace. And as soon as you prove def (1) implies def (2) you get that you have  a bonafide smallest subspace. And if you in turn prove (2) implies (1) you prove that there is only one such smallest subspace which is given by both (1) and (2). The first definition does not reference intersection of subspacese . It independently gives you one( and only one) possible candidate that could be the smallest subspace.